# Wordpress listen to $_POST in functions.php

Tags: functions, ajax

I currently have the following function in my `functions.php` which checks if a username exists in the DB.

```
function check_username() {
       $username = $_POST['user'];
       if ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
           $return['user_exists'] = true; 
       }
       else {
           $return['user_exists'] = false;
       }
       echo json_encode($return);
       die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'check_username');
```

I'm using Ajax to call that function with an appropriate username:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://examle.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    cache : false,
    data : {
        action : 'check_username',
        user: 'test'
    },
    success : function (json) {
        if (json.user_exists) {
            alert(json.user_exists);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that `$username` returns `null` instead of `test`. I've been trying for several hours now different combinations yet they've all returned null.

Assigning this makes the above php function work `$username = 'test';` so I'm pretty sure this isn't an issue with the php code.

So my question is, how do I get the variable `$username` to listen and fetch the correct parameter instead of `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the type

`type : "GET",`

to

`type : "POST",`

Answer (score 2):

While Chinmoy's answer is correct I recommand you to use [wp_send_json](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json). When doing ajax this is really useful. It hanldes every essential part of the process including security.

In real life you can use it like that :

```
wp_send_json_success( $data);//successful requests
wp_send_json_error( $data );// errors
```

They return an array with $data encoded in json and set some boolean to make your life easier with the jQuery part.